# Is there a glitch where the moose won't die?

Tags: dont-starve-together

Me and my friend micro'd the  hell out of this goose, but it just wouldn't die. We blasted it with all of a fire staff, and we had full log armor and battle helms on with battle spears, and it just wouldn't die. Has this happened to other people?

Comment: According to the wiki, the Moose/Goose would take 30 hits from a fire staff before it dies, so you'll need one and a half fire staffs

Comment: Yes, we used up one whole fire staff and then hit the crap out of it with battle spears - this was after we had already been attacking it with battle spears mind you. I think it must be a glitch

Comment: Spears are very weak. Have you tried the same with ham bat? Also, how many hits did you land on it?

Comment: The wiki says 52 hits from a battle spear does a goose in. We probably hit the damn thing like 200 times with it, not including the fire staff. No we didn't use ham bats - they're weaker than the battle spear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that, alas, you simply didn't wound it enough.

The wiki says it takes 58 hits with a battle spear to kill a Moose/Goose.  But that's in regular Don't Starve.  In DST, all boss monsters have doubled hit points.  So now we're looking at 116 hits.

Similarly, 30 hits with a fire staff becomes 60...but you only get 20 hits out of a single fire staff.

Assuming you hit the Moose/Goose with every single fire staff shot (did you?) and assuming the fire staff was full when you started (was it?), you're still looking at 77 spear hits to kill the Moose/Goose...all while it keeps honking and making you drop your spear.

You might consider trying out the [Health Info mod](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=375859599) to help you see whether you're making any decent progress against it next time.

(If your battle was quite recent, you could even try rolling back your game a day or two and giving it another go with the above hit numbers in mind.)

Comment: Incidentally, I can tell you that my son and I managed to kill one the other day, but it was far from easy.  We got lucky when I managed to lure it over a stack of lit gunpowder.

Comment: Gotta be it. We hit it a ton, but maybe we were just shy of killing it